# Concept of power

Tags: power

Does 2000 watt pure resistive load has less resistance than 1000 watt pure resistive load when they are connected to a same voltage?

And because 2000 watt load has less resistance so more current flows through it due to which the load consumes more power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both questions, yes is the correct answer.

You can think a 2000W load being two 1000W loads connected in parallel within one device.